# `traefik.docker.network` label not working as expected?

Tags: docker, traefik

Spent few days trying to figure out how to make standalone traefik (launched through `docker run` or just `traefik` binary on OSX) proxy to containers started with `docker-compose`.

I've narrowed down issue to the networking:

- when traefik and containers share a network – containers receive connections
- but when no shared network is used and `"traefik.docker.network=wf_default"` label is used to instruct traefik how to reach a container - proxy-ing calls timeouts.

Ofcourse workaround is to use shared network, but, to my understanding, isn't `"traefik.docker.network=wf_default"` supposed to solve this problem of having explicitly use shared network?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you get this working.
I seem to have a similar issue, all but one container is working with Traefik, and that one has multiple networks assigned. If I check the Traefik dashboard I see it is trying to connect on the wrong container IP.